# Proving uniform convergence of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $S(a)$ be a series such that
$$
S(a) = \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\binom{k+r-1}{k}a^k,
$$
where $0<a<1$ and $r>0$. Can we show that $S_n$ converges uniformly? Thank you.

Comment: Uniformly with regard to what? The way you wrote it, $n$ is a mysterious parameter, and $a,r$ are constants. Did you mean $S(a)$?

Comment: Yes Clement C, I mean that S(a).

Comment: Hint: $S_r(a)=\frac1{(r-1)!}\left(\frac{a^{r-1}}{1-a}\right)^{(r-1)}$ ($r-1^{th}$ derivative on $a$).